# How can I track the execution flow inside Spring using the logs, to understand its inner workings?

Tags: spring-mvc, log4j

I was trying to see the execution flow inside Spring framework, using the logs printed to the console. The aim was to understand the inner working of Spring framework a little bit. I set the logging level to ALL in my application. Following lines are printed in the logs:

```
2013-07-04 14:46:34 TRACE DispatcherServlet:1018 - Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@13dd208
2013-07-04 14:46:34 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:823 - DispatcherServlet with name 'web' processing GET request for [/webtemplate/]
2013-07-04 14:46:34 TRACE DispatcherServlet:1088 - Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping@fedfb6] in DispatcherServlet with name 'web'
2013-07-04 14:46:34 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:220 - Looking up handler method for path /
2013-07-04 14:46:34 TRACE RequestMappingHandlerMapping:264 - Found 1 matching mapping(s) for [/] : [{[/],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}]
2013-07-04 14:46:34 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:227 - Returning handler method [public java.lang.String com.lister.custom.webtemplate.controller.MainController.index(org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)]
2013-07-04 14:46:34 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:246 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'mainController'
2013-07-04 14:46:34 TRACE DispatcherServlet:1122 - Testing handler adapter [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter@771eb1]
```

I checked the source file(?) and the line number that were printed in all the lines:

- DispatcherServlet:823
- DispatcherServlet:1018
- RequestMappingHandlerMapping:220
- etc...

in an effort to see what was going on inside.

But, in most cases, I was not able to find any relevant code in the respective line numbers. Many had just comments at those line numbers.

Of the above log lines, only `DispatcherServlet:823` had the actual code that printed the log.

**How can I use the logs (DEBUG and TRACE) to track the execution flow inside Spring?**

**Note:**

- The versions of both the binary used by my application and the source I am checking are the same - 3.2.3.RELEASE
- Following is my logger pattern: `log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n` if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the superclass as well. Eg:

```
2013-07-04 14:46:34 TRACE DispatcherServlet:1018 - Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@13dd208
```

Is actually made by FrameworkServlet class line 1018.

Maybe you should configure your log4j logger to also spit out the fully qualified class name (not just the logger name):

```
%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %C{1}:%L - %m%n
```

(notice uppercase C instead of c)